# Accessing Environment variables in Botium.json

Tags: bots, chatbot, botium-box

In Botium.json, "SIMPLEREST_INIT_CONTEXT": { "token": "367439234324243" ,"sessionid":"34546363dfgfg4545"}, This value needs to taken from env variable PROCESS.ENV.token, How can i set in this file so that i can use it in simplerest endpoints ??? example would be great

Comment: I have also tried using SIMPLEREST_START_HOOK, with js file , but botium just executed hook and stopped without running any tests `const request = require('request')
 var myJSONObject = json data here;
module.exports = ({ context }) => {return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    request({url: "http end point here",method: "POST",json: true,headers: {"token": "0jdfhjdfho8re4545340f2"}, body: myJSONObject
    }, function (error, response, body){context.sessionid=response.body.message.key;
       context.client=response.body.client;
        context.token='45435634534jhj45j4j3343; })})}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables can be access within the moustache templates scripting functions, see [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/24510469/Generic+HTTP+S+JSON+Connector#Using-Scripting-Memory-within-Mustache-Templates).

```
...
"SIMPLEREST_INIT_CONTEXT": {
  "token": "{{#fnc.func}}{{process.env.token}}{{/fnc.func}}",
  "sessionid":"34546363dfgfg4545"
}
...
```

It seems as if you want to use the token from the environment variables, and with this token you want to initialize the session before starting a conversation. Could work like this - first make a "ping" request to initialize the session, then use the session id from the ping response body in the following calls:

```
...
"SIMPLEREST_PING_URL": "some url",
"SIMPLEREST_PING_VERB": "POST",
"SIMPLEREST_PING_HEADERS": {
  "token": "{{#fnc.func}}{{process.env.token}}{{/fnc.func}}"
},
"SIMPLEREST_PING_BODY": { some json content for the body },
...
"SIMPLEREST_URL": "...",
"SIMPLEREST_HEADERS_TEMPLATE": {
  "sessionid":"{{context.message.key}}"
},
...
```